# Database sorted by a specific string then random

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli, datatables, sql-order-by

Is there any way to order a database by a specific name stored in a function then random?
For example, if `$name = 'Hasan'` then I want the query to select `Hasan` row first then the other rows randomly

```
<?php 

/* DATA BASE
id          |  Name
--------------+--------------------------------
'1'         |  Hasan
'2'         |  Ahmad   
'3'         |  Majid 
'4'         |  Hazem  
*/

if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
$name = $_GET['name'];
}
else {
$name = 0;
}

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY $name, rand()");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a test on the name in the `ORDER BY` clause, sorting by whether it matches or not. You should use a prepared statement to protect yourself from SQL injection. For example:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY Name = ? DESC, rand()');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // ... do something
}
```

This works because MySQL treats boolean expressions as 0 (false) or 1 (true) in a numeric context, so the value of `Name = $name` will be 1 when the name matches and 0 otherwise, which you can then sort on descending.

Note that [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) is only available with the `mysqlnd` native driver installed. Without that, you will need to use [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), [`mysqli_stmt::store_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) and [`mysqli_stmt::fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a prepared statement here, something along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM database
ORDER BY name != ?;
```

Assuming you bound `Hasan` to the `?` placeholder, this would give:

```
SELECT *
FROM database
ORDER BY name != 'Hasan';
```

This would place all Hasan records first (since false evaluates to 0), with all non Hasan records appearing after that.  Note that your second sort level `RAND()` may not even be necessary, since MySQL does not guarantee any further default sorting order.